# PHP not download apk file correctly on my server

Tags: php, file, download, apk

I must download an apk file from my server, but i have an incomplete download.

This is the code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Zappapp1.0.apk"');
readfile('Zappapp1.0.apk');
```

EDIT

I try this but it not work..

```
$file = 'zappapp.altervista.org/apk/Zappapp1.0.apk';
        if (file_exists($file)) {
             header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
             header('Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive');
             header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
             header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
             header('Expires: 0');
             header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
             header('Pragma: public');
             header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
             ob_clean();
             flush();
             readfile($file);
             exit;
         }
```

Sorry for my english but i'm italian ..

Comment: If you are on apache check /etc/apache2/mods-available/mime.conf if AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive .apk is available.

Comment: my host server is Altervista, i don't know where i can find the mime.conf file...

Comment: Hmm u can also add this to .htacess see here how to do it http://wiki.joyent.com/wiki/display/gen/Configuring+MIME+Types+in+.htaccess

Comment: i do it, i've add AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive .apk to my .htaccess but it still don't work

Comment: hmm thats weird. If its not a security issue you can use header("Location : your file path") this should solve the issue. But I am still confused why its not working for u since your code looks good.

Comment: perfect i resolve it using header("Location: http://zappapp.altervista.org/apk/Zappapp1.0.apk"); =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You Can Try This Maybe Its Help you.............

```
$file = '/home/bla-bla/domains/bla-bla.com/file/file.apk'; //not public folder
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: @user3096313 if my answer is useful then please accept it